# Text box AutoCompleteSource (winForms) and LINQ query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, autocomplete

I have a pre-populated text box with with an AutoCompleteCustomSource:

```
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
using(propertiesManagementDataContext db = new propertiesManagementDataContext())
{
    var q =
        (from t in db.GetTable<Tenant>()
        select t.lname + " " + t.fname).ToArray();
        source.AddRange(q);
}
txt_callerName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
txt_callerName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
txt_callerName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

It works fine, but I want to know the ID of the auto completed item. How to get it?
I tried like this, but had an error:

```
var q =
    (from t in db.GetTable<Tenant>()
    select new {lfname = t.lname + " " + t.fname, t.tenantID}).ToArray();
source.AddRange(q); 
//this does not work, because q is not an array of strings anymore
```

How to autocomplete the textbox and save the connection between Lname, Fname and tenantID of the autocompleted items?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` class that allows you store extra data for each string ... it's pretty much just a collection of strings.

This isn't ideal, but you could include the ID at the end of the string so it doesn't affect the auto-complete experience while the user is typing, then parse the value back out when they make a selection:

```
var q =
    (from t in db.GetTable<Tenant>()
     select string.Format("{0} {1} ({2})", t.lname, t.fname, t.tenantID)).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, you could use a `ComboBox` control, which (when configured properly) does everything your `TextBox` is doing, as well as supports setting the data source to a collection of any class you want (not limited to a collection of strings).

You would then specify the property visible to the user (name) with `DisplayMember` and then the value of each item (ID) with `ValueMember`.

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the additional data in parallel Dictionary (or other similar collection)

```
var q =
    (from t in db.GetTable<Tenant>()
    select new {lfname = t.lname + " " + t.fname, t.tenantID});

Dictionary<String, Int32> idDictionary = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();

foreach(var item in q)
{
    idDictionary.Add(item.lfname, item.tenantID);
    source.AddRange(q);
}

...
String currentSuggestion = ...

Int32 id = idDictionary[currentSuggestion];
dbContext.Entities.RemoveById(id);
```

That is not the ideal solution, because you will have to somehow associate for each textBox with AutoCompletion its own dictionary(either storing it in parallel, or subclassing the TextBox). Also there is possibility that lfname can occur twice in the query.